# How can convert this node.async code to using q? Do I need to return a promise?

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, q

In "view" method within my controller was previously using `node-async` but I wanted to try out using `q`.

I'm currently trying to convert this

```
exports.view = function (req, res) {
    var category = req.params.category,
        id = req.params.id,
        ip = req.connection.remoteAddress,
        slug = req.params.slug,
        submission,
        userId = typeof req.session.user !== 'undefined' && req.session.user.id ? req.session.user.id : null,
        views;
var getSubmission = function (submissionId, callback) {
    Submission.getSubmission({
        id: submissionId
    }, function (err, submission) {
        if (err) {
            callback(err);
        } else if (submission) {
            callback(null, submission);
        } else {
            callback(err);
        }
    });
};


async.waterfall([

function (callback) {
    getSubmission(id, callback);
},

function (submission, callback) {
    res.render('submission', {
        title: submission.title + ' -',
        submission: submission
    });
}]);
```

To using q... I started doing something like:

```
var getSubmission = function(id) {
  return Submission.getSubmission({
    id : submissionId
  }).then(function(submission) {
    return submission;
  });
};

q.fcall(getSubmission).then(function(submission) {
  console.log(submission);
});
```

But it's not quite working as I intended. Am I doing something wrong here? How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is `Submission.getSubmission` a call to a database? Then you can't "chain" promises to that. You'll have to use the `deferred` method:

```
var getSubmission = function(id) {
  var deferred = Q.defer();
  Submission.getSubmission({
    id: id
  }, function(err, data){
    if (err) {
      deferred.reject(err);
    } else {
      deferred.resolve(data);
    }
  });
  return deferred.promise;
}

getSubmission(some_id).then(successCallback, failureCallback);
```

You can also use `Q#denodeify` to convert a function using nodejs-style callbacks (`function(err, data)`) into a promise based function. Thus, the above can also be achieved by the following:

```
getSubmissionPromise = Q.denodeify(Submission.getSubmission);
getSubmissionPromise({id: some_id}).then(successCallback, failureCallback);
```

Comment: Bad ass man thanks. Do I need to create a new deferred within each scope? Like if I chain another call to do something with the submission like getSubmissionViews do I create a new deferred within that scope? Or pass the first one to it?

Comment: If all your async functions always return the same signature (`function(err, data)`), you can use `getSubmissionAsPromise = Q.denodeify(Submission.getSubmission); getSubmissionAsPromise({id: 123}).then(successCallback, errorCallback);`.

Comment: But say I used denodeify and in my `then` wanted to call getCommentsAsPromise({submissionId : submission._id}) but you can see I'd be using the submission id from the returned object from the first denodeify, how would I do that? Aka.. keep the chain going

Comment: Nevermind got it figured out. Needed to a return to the getCommentsAsPromise().